# JavaFX textfield.getText() пустое

Tags: java, javafx

У меня есть .fxml файл с TextField и есть контроллер, в котором я хочу получить значение

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="260.0" prefWidth="400.0" stylesheets="@../css/main.css"
            xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
            fx:controller="com.study.course4.emailclient.controller.StartMenuController">
   <children>
      <TextField fx:id="emailTextField" layoutX="50.0" layoutY="70.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="300.0" promptText="E-mail" />
      <TextField fx:id="passwordTextField" layoutX="50.0" layoutY="120.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="300.0" promptText="Пароль" />
      <Button layoutX="100.0" layoutY="170.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#handleOnLoginButtonClick" prefHeight="15.0" prefWidth="200.0" styleClass="start_menu_button" text="Войти" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

```
package com.study.course4.emailclient.controller;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import net.rgielen.fxweaver.core.FxmlView;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@FxmlView("../resources/view/start_menu.fxml")
public class StartMenuController {

  private StringBuilder errors = new StringBuilder();

  @FXML
  private TextField emailTextField;

  @FXML
  private TextField passwordTextField;

  @FXML
  public void handleOnLoginButtonClick(MouseEvent event){
      System.out.println(emailTextField);
      String email = emailTextField.getText();
      System.out.println(emailTextField.getText());
      String password = passwordTextField.getText();
      System.out.println(password);
      System.out.println("----------------------------");
      errors = new StringBuilder();
      if(email.trim().isEmpty()) errors.append("Email не может быть пустым. \n");
      if(password.equals("")) errors.append("Пароль не может быть пустым. \n");
      if(!email.matches("^.*@(mail[.]ru|gmail[.]com|yandex[.]ru)$")) errors.append("Неподходящий email адрес. \n");
      System.out.println(errors);
  }


}
```

getText() всегда возвращает пустую строку. Подскажите в чем может быть проблема

Comment: Готово, вставил текстом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалил TextField и добавил заново - заработало
Удивлен, но доволен